# negating pandas isna function returning -2

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, boolean-logic

I am a bit confused by inconsistency of how `pd.isna()` work in different settings. Any thoughts around why boolean not `~` doesn't work with `pd.isna` in number settings:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'p':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'q':[1, np.nan, 2]})
>>> df
   p    q
0  a  1.0
1  b  NaN
2  c  2.0
>>> df[~pd.isna(df['q'])]       # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED.
   p    q
0  a  1.0
2  c  2.0
>>> pd.isna(np.nan)
True
>>> not pd.isna(np.nan)
False                           # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED.
#### So far so good ####
>>> ~pd.isna(np.nan)
-2                              # I WAS EXPECTING False HERE.
>>> ~(pd.isna(np.nan))
-2                              # I WAS EXPECTING False HERE.
```

I am not why last two rows fetch `-2` instead of `False`.

Comment: I am not familiar enough to know why your compilier doesn't display the object like I would expected.

Comment: Thanks @Danielme How come it works with `df[~pd.isna(df['q'])] `

Comment: We know ~pd.isna(df['q']) returns bitwise of 'q' filtered isnan, since its already a bool type we get bitwise on a one bit bool (so flips t/f). So we have an array with bools. If you did not know, we could pass df[[True,False,False]] to only print the first row of the data set. The return from isna is doing the same thing and essentially only displaying non nan values. You are passing in a bool per indices to save.

I deleted my first comment since it was incorrect

Comment: Thanks @Danielme. So basically you are saying `~np.array([True]) = array([False]) ` and so is `~pd.Series([True]) = 0    False dtype:bool`. However, `~True = -2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about `pd.isna()` in the last two rows you use `~` that is *Bitwise Not Operator* and it **inverts all the bits of an object** and binary not for `True`(1 in int) is -2:

```py
>>> var = int(True)
>>> var
1
>>> not var
False
>>> ~ var
-2
```

***Boolean*** values like True and False in python are return from comparison, logical and membership operators in python and bitwise operators return int values.

Comment: Thanks @JavadNikbakht. I am still curious why does this same bitwise not operator work in fifth last row, i.e., `df[~pd.isna(df['q'])]`